# Why there is no compilation error when I am using different data types for switch expression and case value in this case

Tags: java, types, switch-statement

```
public class Conditionsif {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int day=1;
        switch(day){
        case '1':
            System.out.println("Monday");
            break;
        
        }
        
    }

}
```

There is no compilation error in above though switch expression is integer data type and case value is character

Comment: JLS 14.11.1 A switch label must be “assignment compatible” - you must be able to assign the value in the label to the type of the switch expression. As `int day = ‘1’` is valid, your code is valid. Note this assigns the value `49` to `day` as that’s the ASCII code for the character “1”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because of implicit casting
ascii value of a is 97

```
 switch(97){
           case 'a': System.out.println("a"); break;
           case 'b': System.out.println("b"); break;
           case 'c': System.out.println("c"); break;
 }
```

Comment: What’s the ascii value of `a` got to do with it?

Comment: He is saying that when we write number in switch expression and character in case, compiler will do implicit conversion of character into ascii value and do comparison with number in switch to give output

Comment: There is no conversion to or from ASCII resp. Unicode values. `97` and `'a'` *are* the same value and `switch` statements operate on `int` anyway. The difference between the `char` value `'a'` and the `int` value `97` is how they will be printed or appended to a string.

Answer (score 0):

When you use ' ', this means you use **char**  data type.
char data type accept one character only ,
for example :
char x = 'h';

And also accept the Ascii code for the character
for example :
char x = 104;

So case '1' mean compare variable day with value equal to value 1.

if you modify code as following , this code will print Monaday.

```
    int day=97;
    switch(day){
    case 'a':
        System.out.println("Monday");
        break;
    }
```

Best Regards.